# SP2019 - Site Collection feature "SharePoint Lists and Libraries experience" missing

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, feature, 2019, classic-experience

I trying to find the SiteCollection feature *SharePoint Lists and Libraries experience* on an SP2019 farm, to revert the look and feel of a classic team site (migrated from SP2013) to the classic experience. But the feature is not there.

I thought it might have something to do, with the site being a migrated site, so I created a new Classic Team SiteCollection on the SP2019 farm and checked, but it doesn't show there as well:

[image: Manage Site Collection features, not showing the desired feature]

Am I missing something? Does this feature need a specific WebApplication or Farm feature enabled? Or another solution installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not missing anything. SharePoint 2019 doesn't have this feature. It is only available in SharePoint online.

If you want to disable the modern experience in SharePoint 2019, you could use the powershell to achieve this.

Site Collection Level:

```
#Site Collection Level
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ea 0
$site = Get-SPSite http://spwfe

#Disable modern Lists and libraries at the Site Collection Level
$featureguid = new-object System.Guid "E3540C7D-6BEA-403C-A224-1A12EAFEE4C4"
$site.Features.Add($featureguid, $true)

#Re-enable the modern experience at the site collection Level.
$featureguid = new-object System.Guid "E3540C7D-6BEA-403C-A224-1A12EAFEE4C4"
$site.Features.Remove($featureguid, $true)
```

Web Level:

```
#Web Level
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ea 0
$site = Get-SPWeb http://spwfe

#Disable modern Lists and libraries at the Web Level.
$featureguid = new-object System.Guid "52E14B6F-B1BB-4969-B89B-C4FAA56745EF"
$site.Features.Add($featureguid, $true)

#Re-enable the modern experience at the Web Level
$featureguid = new-object System.Guid "52E14B6F-B1BB-4969-B89B-C4FAA56745EF"
$site.Features.Remove($featureguid, $true)
```

Library Level:

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ea 0
$web = Get-SPWeb http://spwfe
$list = $web.Lists["Documents"]

#Classic setting
$list.ListExperienceOptions = "ClassicExperience"
$list.Update()

#Modern setting
$list.ListExperienceOptions = "NewExperience"
$list.Update()

#User Default
$list.ListExperienceOptions = "Auto"
$list.Update()
```

Reference:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-support-blog/how-to-disable-the-modern-experience-in-sharepoint-2019/ba-p/303649

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try that immediately. But if the feature doesn't exist in 2019, why is this article flagged for online + 2019: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-the-default-experience-for-lists-or-document-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9

Comment: This worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Credit to Michael Han for his answer.  This is just a conversion to a different language**

I know this is dredging up from the past, but we ran into this exact issue without access to powershell.  I've converted it to JavaScript that can be run in a browser console from any page on the site that is in classic view.

Modern pages will not run this code due to SP.js not being loaded.

Usage:

`Copy and Paste code function snippet into browser console (F12)`

```
function ModernFeature(){
    var featureId = new SP.Guid('E3540C7D-6BEA-403C-A224-1A12EAFEE4C4');
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var site = ctx.get_site();
    var features = site.get_features();
    ctx.load(features);
    return {
        enable: () => {
            features.remove(featureId, true);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                function(){console.log('Enabled Modern Site')},
                function(sender, args){console.error(args.get_message())}
            );
        },
        disable: () => {
            features.add(featureId, true);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                function(){console.log('Disabled Modern Site')},
                function(sender, args){console.error(args.get_message())}
            );
        }
    }
}
```

`Copy and Paste code specific enable/disable snippet into browser console (F12)`

```
var site = new ModernFeature();
site.enable();
```

```
var site = new ModernFeature();
site.disable();
```